# Is there a way to open Windows PowerShell as administrator using Python?

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I have a Surface Pro that is touchscreen so I'm trying to write a Python program that allows me to toggle touchscreen with the click of a button by running this code in PowerShell

This code snippet is to turn off the touchscreen:

```html
Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*'} | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
```

And this code is to turn on the touchscreen:

```html
Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*'} | Enable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
```

I know you can use the subprocess module to open apps, but I don't know about opening as admin

Answer (score 1):

That can be accomplished with the subprocess module

example:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call('<path to powershell>\powershell.exe <command>', shell=True)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying!
Unfortunately, what I've tried doesn't work, have I done anything wrong?

import subprocess

subprocess.call("<C:/Users/windowsCm/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Windows PowerShell>/powershell.exe <Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*'} | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false>", shell=True)

Comment: remove the angular brackets, I only wrote them for your understanding.

Comment: Try using the `saps powershell.exe -verb runas` as the command for the subprocess and see if it prompts you for admin

Comment: So I tried multiple ways, removing the angular brackets, using the command that @NekoMusume suggested. but it gives me this error:

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

I tried replacing the "\"  in the path with "/" but it gives me this error:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Am I using the wrong file path?